# How do I make the function run again when I click again?

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, dom-events

I want to make the ball run the bounce function again after it has ran once. How do I accomplish this with JS strictly?

```
    <script>
    var ball = document.querySelector(".ball");
    var blo = -2;
    function bounce(){
        var hi = setInterval(function(){
            var top = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(ball).getPropertyValue("top"));
            ball.style.top = top + blo + "px";
        },5)
        var ko = setInterval(function(){
            var yo = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(ball).getPropertyValue("top"));
            if(yo==0){
                blo = 2;
            }
            if(yo>400){
                blo = 0;
            }
        },5)
    };
    ball.onclick = bounce;
    
</script>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function your_function (){
  console.log(1);
}
var ball = document.querySelector(".ball");
// new way 
ball.onclick = ()=>{
  your_function();
  your_function()
}

//old way 

// ball.onclick = function () {
//   your_function();
//   your_function()
// }
```

```html
<button class = "ball"> click me </button>
```